# Importing Products with Magmi - Where to Upload CSV?

Tags: magento, magmi

I recently installed the Magmi extension to import products in Magento but can't figure out where I'm supposed to upload the CSV file for it to import. It says I'm supposed to set the CSV file but, after looking around, I'm not seeing any place to click and select the file to upload.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: so did you find the answer to this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

There's no file upload - it asks you to set the directory that the import files go in. So put them in var/import and set that directory in Magmi, save your profile settings. You will then be given a dropdown of all csv files in that directory. Choose one and then run the importer.